# How to make HTML5 range slider behave differently based on click vs. drag input

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50"></input>
```

So I have the code above, and when you move the slider by clicking and dragging the selector in the middle of the slider, it moves up 1 at a time, which is what I want.

The missing functionality I am attempting to create, is if i click anywhere to the right of the selector in the slider, I want the selector to just move up by 5. And the same goes for the left and down.

My first thoughts were to maybe do an onclick listener and check the coordinates of the click vs. the coordinates of the selector, but I'm not sure how to find the coordinates of the latter.

Thanks

**The selector I reference throughout is in the following picture if you weren't sure what I meant.]
[Selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HntmF.png)

Comment: The 'coordinates' of the selector would be the current input value.  ex 50 would be the center.

Comment: But if you're using an onclick listener, you're going to get coordinates like (560, 890). How can I use the 50 in that situation?

Comment: You would need to get the coordinates of the input, its width and do some math